# How to reply to someone who introduced himself

Tags: formal-language, conversation

How can I reply when I chat with a new person and he introduced himself and I want to show that I'm pleased to know him but in formal way

Comment: Do you mean chatting in person, or online in a chat program?  The etiquette is likely different.

Answer (score 1):

All the items in [this answer](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/317772/91457) are fine.

If the person is professionally or socially prominent, or holds public office, one might say

> I am honored to meet you.

If you knew in advance that you would meet this person, you could say:

> I have been looking forward to meeting you.

Including the "I am" at the start of the sentence, and avoiding contractions helps the response seem more formal.

If the situation is formal and the person is male, and particularly if the person is older, one can add "Sir" after the "you". (If the person is female, one can add "Ma'am" or "Madam" as local usage calls for.)

> - I am very pleased to meet you, Sir.
> - I am honored to meet you, Ma'am.

In any case, after the sentene in which yu describe your self as pleased or happy or whatever, you can add your own self-introduction:

> I'm Jon Dark.

after that, follow with some identifying tag that is likely to be helpful to the person yu are meeting, What works depends oin the nature of the event, Possibilities might include:

> - I work over at Megatronics.
> - I'm Fred's brother-in-law.

Answer (score 0):

Various formulas will work and are reasonably formal:

1. Glad to meet you.
2. Happy to know you.
3. Glad to know you.
4. Very pleased to make your acquaintance.
5. Very pleased to meet you.

You also can add "I am"  in front of each of these.

Comment: All of them sound OK to me except for the "know you" versions, because the whole point is that you *don't* know this person yet, you're just meeting them.

Comment: Even so, this expression is widely used.  It's an idiom.

Comment: @stangdon
 "*Glad to know you.*" is short for "Glad to **get to** know you."

Comment: I've never heard anyone say "Glad to know you" in the sense of "get to know you".  It might be limited to certain dialects/regiolects.